# Junk byte injection in Android

Tags: android, obfuscation, bytecode, dalvik

After reading [this](http://dexlabs.org/blog/bytecode-obfuscation) interesting article about code obfuscation in Android, I'm trying to do it for research purposes but after applying the technique into a classes.dex file I'm getting a crash.

The next is the code I'm trying to run after applying the technique:

```
0006e8:                                        |[0006e8] com.example.root.bji.MainActivity.paintGUI:()V
0006f8: 1202                                   |0000: const/4 v2, #int 0 // #0
0006fa: 1a01 0000                              |0001: const-string v1, "" // string@0000
0006fe: 1200                                   |0003: const/4 v0, #int 0 // #0
000700: 1303 1400                              |0004: const/16 v3, #int 20 // #14
000704: 3244 0900                              |0006: if-eq v4, v4, 000f // +0009
000708: 2600 0300 0000                         |0008: fill-array-data v0, 0000000b // +00000003
00070e: 0003 0100 1600 0000 1212 0000 0000 ... |000b: array-data (15 units)
00072c: 0000                                   |001a: nop // spacer
00072e: 0000                                   |001b: nop // spacer
... more NOPs ...
000742: 0000                                   |0025: nop // spacer
000744: 0000                                   |0026: nop // spacer
000746: 1503 087f                              |0027: const/high16 v3, #int 2131230720 // #7f08
...
```

To give you some context, I want to keep clear some assignations like the 0 value into the v2 register at 0x6f8 ("const/4 v2, 0" => 12 02), which will be shown in the GUI at the end of this method (at 0x746 and beyond); and using this obfuscation technique, "hide" the modification of the v2 register setting a value of 1 into the v2 register at 0x716 ("const/4 v2, 1" => 12 12).
If you follow the code at 0x704 the branch is done to 0x716, where the "const/4 v2, 1"r esides, inside the fill-data-array-payload.

And the problem I'm facing is a crash when I'm running the code (I've tried it from 4.3 to 5.1), and what logcat tells me when the crash happens is:

```
W/dalvikvm(13874): VFY: invalid branch target 9 (-> 0xf) at 0x6
W/dalvikvm(13874): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/root/bji/MainActivity;.paintGUI ()V
W/dalvikvm(13874): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x32 at 0x0006
W/dalvikvm(13874): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/root/bji/MainActivity;.paintGUI ()V
W/dalvikvm(13874): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/root/bji/MainActivity;
W/dalvikvm(13874): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/root/bji/MainActivity;)
D/AndroidRuntime(13874): Shutting down VM
```

For what I understand in the logs, the OS is rejecting the "if-eq" jump because the offset pointed (I've tried other branch instructions but the result is the same). The only way the code works is if I point to an offset outside the fill-array-data-payload, but then there is no obfuscation technique applied :P.

Anyone have tried something similar to this technique or have fight against this branch verification rejection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not expected to work.  The bytecode verifier [explicitly checks](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/analysis/DexVerify.cpp#705) all branches for validity.  The question of whether or not an address is an instruction or data is determined by a [linear walk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/analysis/DexVerify.cpp#66) through the method.  Data chunks are essentially very large instructions, so they get stepped over.

You can make this work if you modify the .odex output, and set the "pre-verified" flag on the class so the verifier doesn't examine it again -- but you can't distribute an APK that way.

Comment: Thank you fadden and JesusFreke too. After change the pre-verify flag in the class it worked like a charm on a 4.1 virtual device!.

Answer (score 1):

This "obfuscation" technique worked due to an issue in dalvik. This issue was fixed somewhere around the 4.3 timeframe, although I'm not sure the first released version that contained the fix. And lollipop uses ART, which never had this issue.

Here is the change that fixed this issue: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/57985/

Comment: The commit you pointed to seems to be about invalid access flags, which has nothing to do with the technique described in the question

Comment: Sure it does. The dalvik verifier will reject any class that tries to use this technique. If you look at their sample app, in order to get around this, the dexlabs guys set the CLASS_ISPREVERIFIED flag on the modified classes in the application's dex file, which prevents the dalvik verifier from verifying and rejecting the class. I submitted that change specifically to prevent this obfuscation technique.

Comment: @JesusFreke So is it fixed by now or can junk bytes (or other protection methods like DIVILAR) still be used today? For Instance I know that Google does not compile all code on newer Android versions (cf. Google IO Video of 2014) using ART.It would be interesting if there is any possibility left.